# Verilog: part-select or indexed part-select cannot be applied to memory

Tags: verilog

In Verilog:

For an array `reg queue[3:0] = 4'b1010;` I can do `queue <= {queue[0], queue[3:1]};`
However, when it comes to 2d array `reg [1:0] queue [3:0];`, error reported when I do the same thing to it `queue <= {queue[0], queue[3:1]};`. *"part-slect or indexed part-slect cannot be applied to memory"*

Therefore, I only do it in a stupid way:

```
queue[0] <= queue[1];
queue[1] <= queue[2];
queue[2] <= queue[3];
queue[3] <= queue[0];
```

Is there a better way to do this, like only one sentence.

Thx!

Comment: Are you trying to move each array item to a different index, or are you trying to do a bit-shift on each item? If you're trying to move each item in an array that's probably a bad idea, would be impossible to do with a ram-based array in single cycle.

Comment: @Tim I am try to do rotate right bit shift. But it is actually 1d array shift for 2d array.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use `for loop` to do that:

```
queue[3] = queue[0];
for(i = 2; i >= 0; i = i - 1) begin
  queue[i] = queue[i+1];
end
```

Comment: does it mean I have to define another reg "i", I not sure if it could be synthesized as extra flip-flop. I used to avoid loop.

Comment: The loop is unrolled during synthesis. No hardware is created for `i`. I would declare `i` as `integer` (effectively identical to `reg signed [31:0]`).

Comment: Well, I find that for only this piece, it is no problem to use loop, but when code become longer, it is hard to control the loop. Too much loop would make the synthesis fail. I don't recommend this and prefer type it manually.